# AWS EMR - Spark-shell \ Spark submit - Unrecognized VM option

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-cloud9

I am getting below exception while invoking spark-shell from AWS emr

```
Unrecognized VM option 'CMSClassUnloaadingEnabled'
Did you mean '(+/-)CMSClassUnloadingEnabled'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Spark submit also getting the same exception. Guide me on how to debug this issue.